# Create Bitbucket Pull Request Comment via REST

Tags: rest, curl, bitbucket

I want to create a bitbucket comment after finishing my bamboo build. Unfortunately my rest call didnt work. ALso Im getting no response.
Am I missing something?

```
curl -u "USER:PASSWORD" -X POST -d '{"body": "Your Message to Comment"}' "http://URL/2.0/repositories/OWNER/REPO/pullrequests/ID/comments"
```

Comment: Is it server or cloud?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to give this information. Its Bitbucket Server

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command:

```
curl -u "USER:PASSWORD" --request POST --data '{"text": "YOUR-COMMENT"}' "BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/REPO/pullrequests/ID/comments"
```

Comment: I fixed the answer